# Trouble with Tree Data Structure [Java]

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have this problem to solve. I have to make a Windows Explorer Using Tree Data Structure in Java.
It is not the problem itself that is hard but I get a error which I don't know what it is and how to solve it. At the "DELETE" part I get `NoSuchElementException` error and I found out that `getElement()` doesn't return anything -_-. I have no idea why is that and help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public interface Tree<E> {
// //////////Accessors ////////////

public Tree.Node<E> root();

public Tree.Node<E> parent(Tree.Node<E> node);

public int childCount(Tree.Node<E> node);

// //////////Transformers ////////////
public void makeRoot(E elem);

public Tree.Node<E> addChild(Tree.Node<E> node, E elem);

public void remove(Tree.Node<E> node);

// //////////Iterator ////////////
public Iterator<E> children(Tree.Node<E> node);

// //////Inner interface for tree nodes ////////
public interface Node<E> {

    public E getElement();

    public void setElement(E elem);

}
}


public class SLLTree<E> implements Tree<E> {

// SLLNode is the implementation of the Node interface
class SLLNode<P> implements Node<P> {

    // Holds the links to the needed nodes
    SLLNode<P> parent, sibling, firstChild;

    // Hold the data
    P element;

    public SLLNode(P o) {
        element = o;
        parent = sibling = firstChild = null;
    }

    public P getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(P o) {
        element = o;
    }

}

protected SLLNode<E> root;

public SLLTree() {
    root = null;
}

public Node<E> root() {
    return root;
}

public Tree.Node<E> parent(Tree.Node<E> node) {
    return ((SLLNode<E>) node).parent;
}

public int childCount(Tree.Node<E> node) {
    SLLNode<E> tmp = ((SLLNode<E>) node).firstChild;
    int num = 0;
    while (tmp != null) {
        tmp = tmp.sibling;
        num++;
    }
    return num;
}

public void makeRoot(E elem) {
    root = new SLLNode<E>(elem);
}

public Node<E> addChild(Node<E> node, E elem) {
    SLLNode<E> tmp = new SLLNode<E>(elem);
    SLLNode<E> curr = (SLLNode<E>) node;
    tmp.sibling = curr.firstChild;
    curr.firstChild = tmp;
    tmp.parent = curr;
    return tmp;
}

public void remove(Tree.Node<E> node) {
    SLLNode<E> curr = (SLLNode<E>) node;
    if (curr.parent != null) {
        if (curr.parent.firstChild == curr) {
            // The node is the first child of its parent
            // Reconnect the parent to the next sibling
            curr.parent.firstChild = curr.sibling;
        } else {
            // The node is not the first child of its parent
            // Start from the first and search the node in the sibling list
            // and remove it
            SLLNode<E> tmp = curr.parent.firstChild;
            while (tmp.sibling != curr) {
                tmp = tmp.sibling;
            }
            tmp.sibling = curr.sibling;
        }
    } else {
        root = null;
    }
}

class SLLTreeIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    SLLNode<T> start, current;

    public SLLTreeIterator(SLLNode<T> node) {
        start = node;
        current = node;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (current != null);
    }

    public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (current != null) {
            SLLNode<T> tmp = current;
            current = current.sibling;
            return tmp.getElement();
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (current != null) {
            current = current.sibling;
        }
    }
}

public Iterator<E> children(Tree.Node<E> node) {
    return new SLLTreeIterator<E>(((SLLNode<E>) node).firstChild);
}

void printTreeRecursive(Node<E> node, int level) {
    if (node == null)
        return;
    int i;
    SLLNode<E> tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < level; i++)
        System.out.print("  ");
    System.out.println(node.getElement().toString());
    tmp = ((SLLNode<E>) node).firstChild;
    while (tmp != null) {
        printTreeRecursive(tmp, level + 1);
        tmp = tmp.sibling;
    }
}

public void printTree() {
    printTreeRecursive(root, 0);
}

public int countMaxChildren() {
    return countMaxChildrenRecursive(root);
}

int countMaxChildrenRecursive(SLLNode<E> node) {
    int t = childCount(node);
    SLLNode<E> tmp = node.firstChild;
    while (tmp != null) {
        t = Math.max(t, countMaxChildrenRecursive(tmp));
        tmp = tmp.sibling;
    }
    return t;
}

}


public class WindowsExplorer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int i;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String commands[] = new String[N];

        for (i=0;i<N;i++)
            commands[i] = br.readLine();

        br.close();

        SLLTree<String> tree = new SLLTree<String>();
        tree.makeRoot("c:");

        // vasiot kod ovde...

        int res = 0;
        int brJazli = 0;
        int stuff = 0;
        Tree.Node<String> tekoven = null;
        Tree.Node<String>[] jazli = new Tree.Node[100];
        Tree.Node<String> proverka = null;
        Tree.Node<String> proverkaa = null;
        String[] path = new String[100];

        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            String[] pom = commands[i].split(" ");
            if(pom[0].equals("CREATE")){ 
                if(res == 0){ 
                    Tree.Node<String> a = null; 
                    tekoven = tree.root; 
                    brJazli++; 
                    a = tree.addChild(tekoven, pom[1]); 
                    jazli[brJazli] = a; 
                } else if(res != 0){
                    Tree.Node<String> a = null;
                    a = tree.addChild(tekoven, pom[1]);
                    brJazli++;
                }
            }
            else if(pom[0].equals("OPEN")){ // Open
                res++; 
                for(int j=0; j < brJazli; j++){
                    if(jazli[j].getElement().toString().equals(pom[1])){
                        tekoven = jazli[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(pom[0].equals("DELETE")){ // Delete
                for(int j=0; j < brJazli; j++){
                    if(jazli[j].getElement().toString().equals(pom[1]))
                        tree.remove(jazli[j]);
                }
            }
            else if(pom[0].equals("BACK")){ // Back
                for(int j=0; j < brJazli; j++){
                    if(jazli[j].toString().equals(pom[1]))
                      tekoven = tree.parent(jazli[j]);
                }
            }
            else if(pom[0].equals("PATH")){
                for(int j=0; j < 15; j++){
                    proverkaa = tekoven;
                    proverka = tree.parent(proverkaa);
                    if(proverka.toString().equals("c:")){
                        System.out.print("c:");
                        if(stuff == 0) break;
                        else {
                        for(int k=1; k < stuff; k++)
                        System.out.print("\"" + path[stuff] + "\"");
                        }
                    }
                        else {
                            path[j+1] = proverka.toString();
                            proverkaa = proverka;
                            stuff++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(pom[0].equals("PRINT")){
                tree.printTree();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: If `getElement()` doesn't return anything, does "OPEN" work?

Comment: No it doesn't, everywhere i have getElement() it doesn't work, just give's me NoSuchEl... error :S

Comment: I also forgot to mention that i can post the class with the tree data structure i use in the comment's section if it does any good.

Comment: Please post it in your question by clicking edit. Do not post the code in the comments.

Comment: Okay they are posted now